# OAuth2 in mule connector

Tags: oauth, mule, connector

I am trying to connect to a third party using mule connector.The security scheme for accessing this third party app is OAuth2. I seek help on putting correct configuration in place. Following is my mule (3.5.2) flow:

```
<XXX-auth2:config name="TestAuth" consumerKey="abc" consumerSecret="1234" doc:name="TestAuth">
        <XXX-auth2:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8082" path="callback" remotePort="8082" async="false"/>
    </XXX-auth2:config>
    <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082"  path="testoauth" doc:name="HTTP" />
         <XXX-auth2:authorize config-ref="TestAuth" doc:name="TestAuth"/>
        <logger message="Test Auth output:#[flowVars['tokenId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

I am new to Oauth and have following questions:

1) What is the callback url here and what should I configure it with. Can I just use anything there? Is this url need to be accessible on internet or can I use localhost?
2) How do I test this configuration? I do it by hitting http inbound url ie, http ://localhost:8082/testoauth The output I get is method not allowed (405) error. 
3) If I hit callback url ie, localhost:8082/callback, I get NoAuthorizationCodeFound exception. How to proceed?
4) How I do know if access token is generated properly?
5) Do I need to specifically store the access tokens for future use?

When I hit the url http:/localhost:8082/testoauth, I get the error of method not allowed. I get the response as {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"GET is not allowed"}. Does that indicate my way of obtaining access is wrong or does it mean anything else?
I am stuck at this point. Please help.

Please throw some light on the process of applying OAuth configuration for accessing protected resources.

Answer (score 1):

1)The callback URL is for the OAuth provider to redirect back to your application after the user has authorized the application. The connector will automatically generate an inbound-endpoint and a
HTTP callback for you and passes the URL to the service provider programmatically.
The connector will then listen for this callback on this address.

2)Calling /testoauth needs to be via an HTTP GET in a browser so it can redirect for authorization to the service provider.

Localhost will work fine via a browser.

3)Calling the the callback url directly has no use. It is for the service provider to call to get back to your application with an authorization code that will be used in subsequent requests to their API.

4) Try logging the token after the authorize:

```
<logger level="INFO"
message="The user identification is #[flowVars[
'OAuthAccessTokenId']]" />
```

**Note** this is not the OAuth access token itself, but the Id to objectstore entry that contains the oauth info including the access token etc.

5) No. Mule takes care of this with its internal object store. This can be customized however to other providers and persistence mechanisms etc so that tokens can be shared across Mule instances etc. See http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Object+Stores

Dont like to self promote, but Chapter 4 of http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025726.do covers these questions.

Also the Mule documentation:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+a+Connector+to+Access+an+OAuth+API

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the detailed explanation to each of my questions. However I am little bit confused on to how to use the OAuth for situations where no browser is involved. For example, I have a requirement where my batch job needs to call a third party API which is protected by OAuth2. Can you provide any sample mule flow as to how to go about implementing the same.

Comment: I have added more details to point#2. Please help. I am almost stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you share your connector code? Thats where the magic happens.

Comment: I have answered in your new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938336/mule-oauth2-using-client-credentials-as-grant-type. You are using client-credentials flow so shouldn't use @OAuth2 annotations. YOu will have to roll your own using connection management.