# Manage OAuth(Client_Credentials) Access token using @Connect in mule

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, connector

I am using Mule to develop a custom connector to an external REST API. It is protected by Client_Credentials OAuth. I am using this [Mule OAuth2 using Client Credentials as grant_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938336/mule-oauth2-using-client-credentials-as-grant-type/27940713#27940713) process to successfully obtain the accesstoken. However, now would like to understand if @Connect has efficient ways to allow the token management, avoiding the need for me to obtain a new token every time I call any operation on this connector. Does Mule provide any OOB features for this or shall I develop my own java code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Connection management is handled for you by Mule when using the Connection Management annotations. It is all detailed here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Implementing+Connection+Management

The connector will keep a pool of connections keyed using whichever value you mark with @ConnectionKey. This could be a username or client key if you are using client credentials flow.

Every time you use the connector with the same connection key, the already 'connected' connector will be used from the pool. You can also use the other annotations in the link above for handling expirations etc.